# Soap api calling with ksoap

Tags: android, soap, soapui

how to get proper response in android app. My api original response is display in soapUi software

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <GetSourcesResponse xmlns="...">
     <GetSourcesResult>
        <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
           <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="ITS" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
              <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="ITS">
                       <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                             <xs:element name="CM_CityID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                             <xs:element name="CM_CityName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          </xs:sequence>
                       </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                 </xs:choice>
              </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
           <DocumentElement xmlns="">
              <ITS diffgr:id="ITS1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                 <CM_CityID>645</CM_CityID>
                 <CM_CityName>Ahmednagar</CM_CityName>
              </ITS>
              <ITS diffgr:id="ITS2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                 <CM_CityID>2762</CM_CityID>
                 <CM_CityName>Airoli</CM_CityName>
              </ITS>
           </DocumentElement>
        </diffgr:diffgram>
     </GetSourcesResult>
  </GetSourcesResponse>
```

and i call this api to get response like

```
getResponse
{
  getResponseResult=anyType
  {
    schema=anyType
    {
      element=anyType
      {
        complexType=anyType
        {
          choice=anyType
          {
            element=anyType
            {
              complexType=anyType
              {
                sequence=anyType
                {
                  element=anyType{};
                  element=anyType{};
                };
              }; 
            };
          };
        };
      };
    };
    diffgram=anyType{};
  };
}
```

how to get proper original response
plz help me.....thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use **Wsdl2Code** [tool](http://www.wsdl2code.com/pages/home.aspx)

It's a web tool that helps developers consume .net web services.

1. Open above `schemas` in `browser` save as **.wsdl** extension
2. Upload `file.wsdl` into `Wsdl2Code`
3. Download Auto generated code
4. Paste in your package
5. Use `Service` class for Read, Write and Update from server

sample code from Service class

```
public VectorClass ReadMultiple(VectorClass filter,
        String bookmarkKey, int setSize, List<HeaderProperty> headers) {
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    SoapObject soapReq = new SoapObject(
            "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/classsName",
            "ReadMultiple");
    for (int i = 0; i < filter.size(); i++) {
        soapReq.addProperty("filter", getSOAPVector(filter, i));
    }
    // soapReq.addProperty("filter", filter);
    soapReq.addProperty("bookmarkKey", bookmarkKey);
    soapReq.addProperty("setSize", setSize);
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);
    NtlmTransport ntml = new NtlmTransport(url,
            SharedPreferenceUtil.getString("userName", "username"),
            SharedPreferenceUtil.getString("passWord", "password"),
            SharedPreferenceUtil.getString("domainName", "domainname"),
            SystemService.domainName);
    try {
        if (headers != null) {
            ntml.call(
                    "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/className/ReadMultiple",
                    soapEnvelope, headers);
        } else {
            ntml.call(
                    "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/className/ReadMultiple",
                    soapEnvelope);
        }
        Object retObj = soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
        if (retObj instanceof SoapFault) {
            SoapFault fault = (SoapFault) retObj;
            Log.e("Fault", "" + fault);
            Exception ex = new Exception(fault.faultstring);
            if (eventHandler != null)
                eventHandler.Wsdl2CodeFinishedWithException(ex);
        } else {
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) retObj; //Soap success response
            if (result.getPropertyCount() > 0) {
                Object obj = result.getProperty(0);
                SoapObject j = (SoapObject) obj;
                Log.e("Navpos Header Response", ""+result);
                VectorClassName resultVariable = new VectorClassName(
                        j);

                return resultVariable;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (eventHandler != null)
            eventHandler.Wsdl2CodeFinishedWithException(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: How is this addressing the OP's problem?

Comment: it's addressing `how to get proper response in android app`